# Up/Down Navigation in Bash Multi-line Command

Tags: bash

Is there any way to save the command into bash history as the multiline command and then to navigate up and down to make some edits and run it again?

```
$ shopt -s cmdhist
$ shopt -s lithist
$ echo "1"\
&& echo "2"\
&& echo "3"
```

Now, if I hit the up-arrow I'd like to see the

```
$ echo "1"\
&& echo "2"\
&& echo "3"
```

..again, but bash gives me the `echo "1"&& echo "2"&& echo "3"`. I.e. it removed the new lines although the `cmdhist` and `lithist` flags are set.

If the up-arrow worked and displayed the multi-line command, how can I navigate up and down in it?

Comment: No, I don't think there is any easy way to accomplish that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible in `Bash` as `\` before a newline is ignored in `Bash`. From `man bash`:

> A non-quoted backslash () is the escape character. It preserves the
>   literal value of the next character that follows, with the exception
>   of . If a \ pair appears, and the backslash is not
>   itself quoted, the \ is treated as a line continuation (that
>   is, it is removed from the input stream and effectively ignored).

If you're willing to change your shell or want to experiment check out `zsh`, it can do what you're looking for:

```
$ echo a \
echo b
```

Press <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd> and see that newlines are retained:

```
$ echo a \
echo b
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure the OP has moved on to new challenges, but for posteriority:

If you are using `&&` to make these three commands into one to keep them in one single history entry (rather than to abort on error), consider instead making a parenthesized command:

```
$ (echo "1"
echo "2"
echo "3")
```

The parenthesized expression is treated as a single command and if you have `shopt -s lithist` the newlines are preserved.

Be aware though that commands within are executed in a subshell. Any variable assignments made are discarded after the command completes and the subshell is exited.

Comment: Good idea - - to avoid the subshell, use `{ ... }` instead.

Answer (score 1):

> .... displayed the multi-line command, how can I navigate up and down in it?

You can't navigate up and down in a multi-line command from the history,  because bash is saving the command as a single line with embedded new lines or semicolons (depending on `lithist`). Navigating by word does work though, and jumps across the embedded newlines: `Alt-Left/Right`.

Alternatively, the key-combo `Ctrl-x Ctrl-e` opens the multi-line command in a text editor so you can edit it comfortably. Then if you save and quit the editor, bash will echo the command back and run it.

The default editor is set using the VISUAL and/or EDITOR environment variables. To cancel executing the command after you're in the editor, completely erase the contents of the file before saving it and quitting the editor.